# animate jquery toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

Wondering if anyone can tell me how to animate this so that the answer shows gradually? I've added all my code below. Any help to get this working would be very much appreciated.

```
<div class="q-a-set">
<div class="licensing-question" id="q_1">
<i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down" aria-label="Answer"></i> <span>Do I need to pay?</span>
</div>
<div class="licensing-answer-closed" id="a1"><span class="licensing-answer">Yes</span></div>
</div>

.licensing-question{
        font-size: 2.2em;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        color: #a8a8a8;
        cursor: pointer;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline;

    }
    .licensing-answer-closed{
        height: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .licensing-answer{
        color: #222222;
        font-size: 1.8em;

    }

var showAnswerBtn = $(".licensing-question");
var caret = showAnswerBtn.find('.fa');


showAnswerBtn.click(function () {
    //alert(caret);
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = this.id.split('_');
    var id = "a" + target[1];

    $("#" + id).toggleClass('licensing-answer-closed');
    $(caret).toggleClass('fa-caret-square-o-up');

});
```

Comment: where's your html/css? You might try adding `.answer-closed { transition: opacity 1s; opacity: 0; }` but it's kind of unclear what you're trying to do without more context

Comment: I've added it to my question, above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css `transition` with `opacity`. I added a class to your HTML so I can use a class selector to establish the `transition`.

```js
var showAnswerBtn = $(".licensing-question");
var caret = showAnswerBtn.find(".fa");

showAnswerBtn.click(function() {
  //alert(caret);
  event.preventDefault();
  var target = this.id.split("_");
  var id = "a" + target[1];

  $("#" + id).toggleClass("licensing-answer-closed");
  $(caret).toggleClass("fa-caret-square-o-up");
});
```

```css
.licensing-question {
  font-size: 2.2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: #a8a8a8;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}
.licensing-answer-closed {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.licensing-answer {
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
.licensing-answer-parent {
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="q-a-set">
  <div class="licensing-question" id="q_1">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down" aria-label="Answer"></i> <span>Do I need to pay?</span>
  </div>
  <div class="licensing-answer-closed licensing-answer-parent" id="a1"><span class="licensing-answer">Yes</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't add the # for id in var id but add it in your selector

```
var id = "a" + target[1]; // take out -> "#"
$("#" + id).toggleClass('answer-closed');
```

Do the same for "caret".

Comment: Don't see any connection to animations.

Answer (score -1):

**If you use jQuery UI :** https://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/

```
.toggleClass(className, duration)
```

Comment: Hi Thai, this should be a comment, not an answer because it doesn't provide a solution. But in this case, there's no need. OP is using `$.toggleClass()`, the question is about *how to animate `$.toggleClass()`*